Real centers for a log resolution
I am trying to understand resolution of singularities over the complex numbers. What I mean are log resolutions in the sense of Lazarsfeld's book Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I from where I took the following theorem:

On the way, I was asking myself the following question:

If $X$ and $D$ are defined over $\mathbb R$ (say they are locally defined by real polynomials), can the morphism $\mu$ then be chosen to be defined over $\mathbb R$? Or, more specifically, can we choose the centers for the blow-ups to be defined over $\mathbb R$?

I suppose that this is true because in Hironaka's original paper, he does everything over an arbitrary field of characteristic zero, and what sense would it make to define the resolution over a proper field extension? But it would be very helpful for me if someone could point out a reference, where this is spelled out more explicitely.
Thank you in advance!
